# Understanding the convertible_to concept in c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm still new to the C++20 concepts and I want to know why this does not work. I want to create  a function template that concatenates numbers as strings. So I wanted to try concepts. I used `std::convertible_to` to check whether the entered datatype (which is `int` in this case) can be converted to `std::string`. But I'm facing an error that I don't understand.

```
//building the concept
template <typename T>
concept ConvertibleToStdString = std::convertible_to<T,std::string>;

//using the concept
template <ConvertibleToStdString T>
std::string concatenate(T a, T b){
    return std::to_string(a) + std::to_string(b);
}

int main(){

    int x{623};
    int y{73};

    auto result = concatenate(x,y);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp:21:34: error: use of function 'std::string concatenate(T, T) [with T = int; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]' with unsatisfied constraints
   21 |     auto result = concatenate(x,y);
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Convertible to doesn't check overloads of `to_string()`. Such overloads are not considered conversions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You appear to want a concept for types that can be passed to `std::to_string()`.

This code will achieve that.

```
template <typename T>
concept ConvertibleToStdString = requires(T a){ std::to_string(a); };
```

> What am I doing wrong ?

You are misunderstanding the meaning of [`std::convertible_to<T,std::string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to).

That concept validates (among other things) that `T` can **implicitly** convert to a `std::string`, as in:

```
std::string s;
s = 623;   // This will NOT compile.  int is not convertible_to std::string
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've just tried the following syntax: why does this work? 
`template <typename T>
concept ConvertibleToStdString = requires (T a) { 
    std::convertible_to<T, std::string>;
};`

Comment: @Gaston That syntax simply asks, "Does `std::convertible_to<T, std::string>`" _compile_?  It has no check on the meaning or result of the evaluation.