# Concept for constraining parameter pack to string-like types or types convertible to string

Tags: c++, c++20, stdstring, c++-concepts, parameter-pack

I'm piecing together a C++20 puzzle. Here's what I want to do: Function `append_params` will concatenate the url together with additional query parameters. To make design this in a dynamic and extensible way, I wanted to write a concept such that

1. it allows types that an std::string can be constructed from
2. it allows types convertible to string using std::to_string()

   ```
    template<typename... Ts> requires requires(T a) { std::to_string(a); }
    auto append_params(std::pmr::string url, Ts... args) {

    }
   ```
3. it works for a pack of parameters

I've found useful information on point 2) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73430379/understanding-the-convertible-to-concept-in-c20). However, for point 1) and 3) I'm rather clueless (I'm also new to concepts). How can I constrain the whole parameter pack (what's the syntax here?) and how can I make sure that from every parameter I can construct an std::string object?

Also, I would have to know at compile time if I want to use std::strings constructor or std::to_string to handle the case.

Comment: "*it works for a pack of parameters*" Why is that necessary? If a concept handles 1&2, then you can just say `template<concept_name ...Pack>`. The concept itself need not be able to be given a pack.

Comment: Also, the example code you use uses `pmr::string`. `to_string` doesn't use `pmr::string`; it only returns `std::string`. The main reason to use `pmr::string` is because you want to do all necessary memory allocations outside of the heap. Which `to_string` cannot do. So, are you sure you want to use `to_string` here?

Comment: @NicolBolas Right there's no `std::to_pmr_string()`... You're right I'm kinda limited in my options.

Comment: The "old" "forward to implementation" way: `template <typename... Ts> auto append_params(Url url, Ts... args) -> decltype(((url += to_string(args)), ...)) { return ((url += to_string(args)), ...); }`?

Comment: @Jarod42: `std::to_string` doesn't work on `std::string` or types convertible to `std::string`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: As you point in your answer, there is the (unconstrained) implementation missing. Just replace `to_string` with your `make_concatenable` (return type check is still missing with my method though). As I said *"forward to implementation"* ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing a concept, *always* start with the template code you want to constrain. You may adjust that code at some point, but you always want to start with that code (unconstrained).

So what you want is something like this:

```
 template<typename... Ts>
 auto append_params(std::string &url, Ts... &&args)
 {
    return (url + ... + std::forward<Ts>(args) );
 }
```

This doesn't work if any of the types in `args` are not `std::string`s or something that can be concatenated with `std::string`. But you want more. You want to take types which `std::to_string` can be used on.

Note that this is a pretty bad interface, since `std::to_string` cannot be extended by the user. They can make their types convertible to `std::string` or some other concatenate-able string type like `string_view`. But users cannot add overloads to `std` library stuff, so they can't make a type `to_string`able.

Regardless, to allow `to_string` to work, we would need to change the code to concatenate with this expression: `std::to_string(std::forward<Ts>(args))`. But that would *only* take types that `to_string` works on, not types convertible to a `string`.

So what we need is a new function which will use `to_string` if that is appropriate or just return the original expression if it can be concatenated directly.

So we have two kinds of types: those that are inherently string-concatenatable, and those which are `to_string`-able:

```
template<typename T>
concept is_direct_string_concatenatable = requires(std::string str, T t)
{
  {str + t} -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};

template<typename T>
concept is_to_stringable = requires(T t)
{
  {std::to_string(t)} -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};

//Combines the two concepts.
template<typename T>
concept is_string_concatenable =
  is_direct_string_concatenatable<T> ||
  is_to_stringable <T>;

template<is_string_concatenable T>
decltype(auto) make_concatenable(T &&t)
{
  //To_string gets priority.
  if constexpr(is_to_stringable<T>)
    return std::to_string(std::forward<T>(t));
  else
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

So now your template function needs to use `make_concatenable` and the concept:

```
template<is_string_concatenable ...Ts>
auto append_params(std::string url, Ts&& ...args)
{
   return (url + ... + make_concatenable(std::forward<Ts>(args)));
}
```

Comment: That is a brilliant answer which also helps me understand concepts and their use more! Thank you so much!